# React Native Change Default iOS Simulator Device

Tags: ios, react-native

When I run this command:

```
react-native run-ios
```

My app runs by default in the iPhone6 simulator device:

```
Found Xcode project RN.xcodeproj
Launching iPhone 6 (9.2)...
```

How can I have the app run in a different simulator device (like iPhone5s) by default?

Comment: Xcode --> Product --> Destination ??

Comment: I don't know how to setup default device, but after running `react-native run-ios` you can change device in `Simulator > Hardware > Device > iOS x.x > iPhone 5`. This will work until you quit simulator.

Answer (score 769, accepted):

Specify a simulator using the `--simulator` flag.

These are the available devices for iOS 14.0 onwards:

```
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 8"
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 8 Plus"
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 11"
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 11 Pro"
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 11 Pro Max"
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone SE (2nd generation)"
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 12 mini"
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 12"
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 12 Pro"
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 12 Pro Max"
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 13 Pro"
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 13 Pro Max"
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 13 mini"
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 13"
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPod touch (7th generation)"
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad Pro (9.7-inch)"
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad (9th generation)"
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad Air (4th generation)"
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation)"
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation)"
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad mini (6th generation)"
```

List all available iOS devices:

```
xcrun simctl list devices
```

There is currently no way to set a default.

[React Native Docs: Running On Simulator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-simulator-ios)

Comment: And if you want; `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad Air"`

Comment: To see all the available devices you can use `xcrun simctl list devices` more info [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-simulator-ios.html)

Comment: Just in case if you have multiple simulator with same name for example iPhone 6s for ios 11 , iPhone 6s for ios 12 etc, then you can set specific name to simulator from Xcode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators

Comment: Why multiple "iPad Pro"s ?

Comment: If you need a specific OS version add it in parentheses: `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 11 Pro Max (13.4)"`

Comment: I want to add a few steps here. Once you have a list of devices, you may find them in shutdown state. In terminal line take help from xcrun simctl and I could boot a iPhone 12 device using `xcrun simctl boot 99FA37C5-9C59-4E1C-AD98-DCD00EAA0CA` and shutdown previous device using xcurn simptl shutdown (deviceID). Next time ios simulator should open your app in new device.

Answer (score 69):

You can also use **npm** for this by adding an entry to the `scripts` element of your `package.json` file. E.g.

```
"launch-ios": "react-native run-ios --simulator \"iPad Air 2\""
```

Then to use this: `npm run launch-ios`

Comment: IMHO this is the best answer as it allows you to store the config in code/version control. Means you dont need to remember the command line syntax.

Comment: I agree with this answer. You can also get by with singlequotes:

`"launch-ios": "react-native run-ios --simulator 'iPad Air 2'"`

Comment: just a small improvement of  `=` and single qotes as mentioned by @ifkwtz, i used in my scripts like : ```"ios:tpmx": "npx react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 12 Pro Max'"```

Comment: I also think this should be marked as the answer since it kinda addresses the "default" device issue with the script entry

Answer (score 43):

There are multiple ways to achieve this:

1. By using `--simulator` flag
2. By using `--udid` flag

Firstly you need to list all the available devices. To list all the devices run

```
xcrun simctl list devices
```

This will give output as follows:

> These are the available devices for iOS 13.0 onwards:

```
== Devices ==
-- iOS 13.6 --
    iPhone 8 (5C7EF61D-6080-4065-9C6C-B213634408F2) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 8 Plus (5A694E28-EF4D-4CDD-85DD-640764CAA25B) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 11 (D6820D3A-875F-4CE0-B907-DAA060F60440) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 11 Pro (B452E7A1-F21C-430E-98F0-B02F0C1065E1) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 11 Pro Max (94973B5E-D986-44B1-8A80-116D1C54665B) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone SE (2nd generation) (90953319-BF9A-4C6E-8AB1-594394AD26CE) (Booted) 
    iPad Pro (9.7-inch) (9247BC07-00DB-4673-A353-46184F0B244E) (Shutdown) 
    iPad (7th generation) (3D5B855D-9093-453B-81EB-B45B7DBF0ADF) (Shutdown) 
    iPad Pro (11-inch) (2nd generation) (B3AA4C36-BFB9-4ED8-BF5A-E37CA38394F8) (Shutdown) 
    iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation) (DBC7B524-9C75-4C61-A568-B94DA0A9BCC4) (Shutdown) 
    iPad Air (3rd generation) (03E3FE18-AB46-481E-80A0-D37383ADCC2C) (Shutdown) 
-- tvOS 13.4 --
    Apple TV (41579EEC-0E68-4D36-9F98-5822CD1A4104) (Shutdown) 
    Apple TV 4K (B168EF40-F2A4-4A91-B4B0-1F541201479B) (Shutdown) 
    Apple TV 4K (at 1080p) (D55F9086-A56E-4893-ACAD-579FB63C561E) (Shutdown) 
-- watchOS 6.2 --
    Apple Watch Series 4 - 40mm (D4BA8A57-F9C1-4F55-B3E0-6042BA7C4ED4) (Shutdown) 
    Apple Watch Series 4 - 44mm (65D5593D-29B9-42CD-9417-FFDBAE9AED87) (Shutdown) 
    Apple Watch Series 5 - 40mm (1B73F8CC-9ECB-4018-A212-EED508A68AE3) (Shutdown) 
    Apple Watch Series 5 - 44mm (5922489B-5CF9-42CD-ACB0-B11FAF88562F) (Shutdown)
```

Then from the output you can select the name or the uuid then proceed as you wish.

1. To run using `--simulator` run:

```
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone SE"
```

2. To run using `--udid` flag run:

```
npx react-native run-ios --udid 90953319-BF9A-4C6E-8AB1-594394AD26CE
```

I hope this answer helped you.

Comment: this is best answer and most straight forward one .... thank you

Comment: I managed to run the app from Xcode on my device, but when I was running npx react-native run-ios, it was always running on simulator. npx react-native run-ios --udid [device id] did the trick for me. Thank you! +1

Answer (score 28):

You can create an alias at your `~/.bash_profile` file:

`alias rn-ios="react-native run-ios --simulator \"iPhone 5s (10.0)\""`

And then run react-native using the created alias:

`$ rn-ios`

Answer (score 28):

There is a project setting if you hunt down:

`{project}/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js`

Within there are some options under `module.exports` including:

`options: [{
    command: '--simulator [string]',
    description: 'Explicitly set simulator to use',
    default: 'iPhone 7',
  }`

Mine was line 231, simply set that to a valid installed simulator and run
`react-native run-ios` it will run to that simulator by default.

Comment: This actually worked, although file was hidden inside {project}/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/

Comment: Great solution. Thanks!

Comment: I don't actually have that module under node modules folder.

Comment: Yup, adding `"runArguments": [
                "--simulator",
                "iPhone 5s"
              ]` to my launch configuration worked perfectly.

Answer (score 24):

1) Rename your simulator, If simulator with same name but different iOS version

```
Xcode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators -> Simulators.
```

[image]

2) Open your react native project folder

3) Edit **package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "flow": "node_modules/.bin/flow",
    "start-iphone6": "react-native run-ios --simulator \"iPhone 6 11.3\""
}
```

4) `npm run start-iphone6`

Answer (score 8):

Update:

```
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 14"
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 13"
```

---

Get device list with this command

```
xcrun simctl list devices
```

Console

```
== Devices ==
-- iOS 13.5 --
    iPhone 6s (9981E5A5-48A8-4B48-B203-1C6E73243E83) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 8 (FC540A6C-F374-4113-9E71-1291790C8C4C) (Shutting Down) 
    iPhone 8 Plus (CAC37462-D873-4EBB-9D71-7C6D0C915C12) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 11 (347EFE28-9B41-4C1A-A4C3-D99B49300D8B) (Shutting Down) 
    iPhone 11 Pro (5AE964DC-201C-48C9-BFB5-4506E3A0018F) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 11 Pro Max (48EE985A-39A6-426C-88A4-AA1E4AFA0133) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone SE (2nd generation) (48B78183-AFD7-4832-A80E-AF70844222BA) (Shutdown) 
    iPad Pro (9.7-inch) (2DEF27C4-6A18-4477-AC7F-FB31CCCB3960) (Shutdown) 
    iPad (7th generation) (36A4AF6B-1232-4BCB-B74F-226E025225E4) (Shutdown) 
    iPad Pro (11-inch) (2nd generation) (79391BD7-0E55-44C8-B1F9-AF92A1D57274) (Shutdown) 
    iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation) (ED90A31F-6B20-4A6B-9EE9-CF22C01E8793) (Shutdown) 
    iPad Air (3rd generation) (41AD1CF7-CB0D-4F18-AB1E-6F8B6261AD33) (Shutdown) 
-- tvOS 13.4 --
    Apple TV 4K (51925935-97F4-4242-902F-041F34A66B82) (Shutdown) 
-- watchOS 6.2 --
    Apple Watch Series 5 - 40mm (7C50F2E9-A52B-4E0D-8B81-A811FE995502) (Shutdown) 
    Apple Watch Series 5 - 44mm (F7D8C256-DC9F-4FDC-8E65-63275C222B87) (Shutdown)
```

Select Simulator string without ID here is an example.

**iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation)**

Final command

> iPhone

• iPhone 6s

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 6s"
```

• iPhone 8

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 8"
```

• iPhone 8 Plus

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 8 Plus"
```

• iPhone 11

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 11"
```

• iPhone 11 Pro

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 11 Pro"
```

• iPhone 11 Pro Max

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 11 Pro Max"
```

• iPhone SE (2nd generation)

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone SE (2nd generation)"
```

> iPad

• iPad Pro (9.7-inch)

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad Pro (9.7-inch)"
```

• iPad (7th generation)

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad (7th generation)"
```

• iPad Pro (11-inch) (2nd generation)

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad Pro (11-inch) (2nd generation)"
```

• iPad Pro (12.9-inch) 4th generation

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation)"
```

• iPad Air (3rd generation)

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad Air (3rd generation)"
```

Answer (score 6):

As answered by Ian L, I also use NPM to manage my scripts.

Example:

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "ios": "react-native run-ios --simulator=\"iPad Air 2\"",
    "devices": "xcrun simctl list devices"
  }
}
```

This way, I can quickly get what I need:

1. List all devices: `npm run devices`
2. Run the default simulator: `npm run ios`

Answer (score 5):

Here is new path for changing iOS simulator you just need to change

```
default: 'iPhone 6' or something else
```

Path:

```
<project_root>/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/runIOS/runIOS.js
```

Comment: In my case file here : `node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js`

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 14"
```

Or Go to xcode and add a new simulator with the name "iPhone 6 (9.2)"
(if you don't want to add  `--simulator="iPhone 14"` each time )

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue with XCode 10.2 specifying the correct iOS simulator version number, so used:

```
react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone X (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-1)'
```

Answer (score 2):

for iPhone Xʀ Simulator

```
    "iosxr": "react-native run-ios --simulator=\"iPhone Xʀ\"",
```

just add this to your scripts in package.json file

the letter "ʀ" used here is a different Unicode than "R"

then hit `$ yarn iosxr` to launch the app on iPhone Xʀ Simulator

Answer (score 1):

I developed CLI tool for it.You can just type "rndcli".and select device

https://github.com/nazrdogan/rndcli

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change default device and only have to run react-native run-ios you can search in finder for keyword "runios" then open folder and fixed index.js file change 'iphone X' to your device in need.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCtR1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwz9T.png)

Answer (score 1):

for RN 0.64.2, the configuration is located at `node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js`, you can just revise the default simulator in the file

Answer (score 0):

1st case:
It happened on a login screen, where I had `autoFocus` on an `TextInput`. Commented that out and everything went back to normal.

2nd case:
With Expo!

After an update of XCode I was getting always the iPhone 12 Max simulator, but I prefered the iPhone 8. So here are the steps I took:

1. While simulator on focus, go to `File -> Open Simulator` and choose the one you wish to be the default.
2. Close the old simulator, close the `localhost:19002` and stop the server in your terminal with `ctr + C`.
3. Run `npm start` and then press `i`.

Now it's running on the simulator you left open.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

React Native will run the first device it finds in the list of simulators (If no simulator is supplied in the run command). To have it run a specific sim as the "default", you can re-order your x-code simulator list by deleting simulators and re-adding them. The first simulator (the one at the bottom of the list) is the one that will be run.

Answer (score 0):

the best and the easiest way to change iOS device is :
1- open simulator [image]
2- choose file > open simulator > then choose the device you want

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

Run this command to see available simulators:

```
xcrun simctl list devices
```

and then run the command with the simulator that you want:

```
npm run ios -- --simulator="iPhone SE (3rd generation)"
```

---

Or tou can add an entry to the ***scripts*** element of your ***package.json*** file. E.g.

```
"launch-ios": "npm run ios -- --simulator=\"iPhone SE (3rd generation)\""
```

Then just use this:

```
npm run launch-ios
```

Answer (score -4):

change line code of /node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js

line 55

```
  if (
    simulator.availability !== '(available)' &&
    simulator.isAvailable !== true
  ) {
    continue;
  }
```

replace which:

```
   if (
                simulator.availability !== '(available)' &&
                simulator.isAvailable !== true
              ) {
                continue;
     }
```