# React Native: Default iOS device inside simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs, react-native, ios-simulator

When running a react native application the device simulator for some reason always defaults to iPhone 6, part of the output:

```
$ react-native run-ios
Found Xcode project AwesomeProject.xcodeproj
Launching iPhone 6 (9.3)...
```

The device can be changed only through `Hardware>Device` menu once the simulator is running.

I have set up Xcode to use an older iPhone version inside the simulator, but it works only inside the IDE and not in CLI.

How to change the default iOS device when running through `react-native` in CLI?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native Change Default iOS Simulator Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328942/react-native-change-default-ios-simulator-device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to set default value by changing this file:

`node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js`

This block is useful for setting iOS simulator, Xcode scheme and root project location:

```
const args = parseCommandLine([
    {
      command: 'simulator',
      description: 'Explicitly set simulator to use',
      type: 'string',
      required: false,
      default: 'iPhone 6',
    }, {
      command: 'scheme',
      description: 'Explicitly set Xcode scheme to use',
      type: 'string',
      required: false,
    }, {
      command: 'project-path',
      description: 'Path relative to project root where the Xcode project (.xcodeproj) lives. The default is \'ios\'.',
      type: 'string',
      required: false,
      default: 'ios',
    }
  ], argv);
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently there seems no way to set the default.
You can use this

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 5"
```

to run on the custom simualtor as discussed in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328942/react-native-change-default-ios-simulator-device).

Answer (score 0):

1) Rename your simulator, If simulator with same name but different iOS version

```
Xcode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators -> Simulators.
```

[image]

2) Open your react native project folder

3) Edit **package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "flow": "node_modules/.bin/flow",
    "start-iphone6": "react-native run-ios --simulator \"iPhone 6 11.3\""
}
```

4) `npm run start-iphone6`