# Change device without using xcode react-native

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native version .28 and created a project which works fine.

I can run it through two ways either from xcode and other from command: `react-native run-ios`

But I do not want to use Xcode, I only want to use the command, but through command, I can chose only a default device: Iphone 6(9.2)

How can I change the device?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native Change Default iOS Simulator Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328942/react-native-change-default-ios-simulator-device)

Comment: @DanielBasedow My question is totally different, I want to know How to change the device like from iphone 5s to 6?

Comment: What do you mean by "change"? If you want to run on iPhone 5s you use `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 5s"` if you want to run on iPhone 6 you type `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 6"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can change the device by running:

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 6"
```

or if you want to make it default you can create an alias at ~/.bash_profile file:

```
alias rn-iphone6="react-native run-ios  --simulator \"iPhone 6\""
```

after that run it by the created alias:

```
rn-iphone6
```