# Change iOS simulator device in launch.js for react native project

Tags: ios, react-native, simulator, launch

I am looking to modify launch.json such that I can change the simulated iOS device used to debug a react native app.
The default configuration for debugging an iOS reactive native app looks like this:

```
{
        "name": "Debug iOS",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
        "type": "reactnative",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "ios",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
}
```

I have tried changing the "name" field to one of the device names in the list generated by running

```
xcrun simctl list devices
```

For example, I have set

```
"name": "iPhone 7"
```

But this does not work.
I am aware of the solution posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37329896/5563513 but I am looking to see if (and if so, how) I can set the simulated device in launch.json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the lines below into your `.vscode/settings.json` file (*create if now exist*)

```
{
    "react-native.ios.runArguments.simulator": [
        "--simulator", "iPhone 6"
    ]
}
```