# Change default iOS simulator device in react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator

Every time I run `react-native run-ios` my project starts by default on iPhone 11.

How can I load my app on a different simulator model?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Change Default iOS Simulator Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328942/react-native-change-default-ios-simulator-device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `--simulator` flag to change your device model. For example:

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 13"
```

Run `xcrun simctl list devices` to get a list of available devices